# Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables of the discrete type. Simplify $\text{Cov}(X+2Y, 3X-Y)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Let X and Y be independent random variables of the discrete type. Simplify $Cov(X+2Y, 3X-Y)$

$$=\text{Cov}(X,X)+(-2) \:\text{Cov}(Y,Y)+(-1)\:\text{Cov}(X,Y)+6 \:\text{Cov}(Y,X)$$

I am not sure how to proceed further.

Comment: Cov(X,X) is the variance of X, and Cov(X,Y) = 0 because X and Y are independent. However note that there should be a 3 in front of your Cov(X,X) term

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathrm{Cov}(\cdot, \cdot)$ admits the same properties as a scalair product. Then, for all $a, \, b\in \mathbb R$ and $X, \, Y$ random variables defined on the sames probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$, we have:
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Cov}(a X+ b Y, c X+ d Y) &  =  ac \mathrm{Cov}(X,X) + ad \mathrm{Cov}(X,Y) \\
&  + bc \mathrm{Cov}(Y,X) + bd \mathrm{Cov}(Y,Y) \\
& = ac \mathrm{Var}(X) + bd \mathrm{Var}(Y) + (ad + bc) \mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)
\end{align*} 
Where $\mathrm{Var}(X)$ is the variance of $X$.

The same is true for the conditional case.